# Removing class elements from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, iframe, removeclass

Now lets say I have this code set up.

```
<html>
<iframe id="content" src="http://www.newgrounds.com/" height="600px"   width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
//some code here
</script>
</html>
```

Let's say I want to remove certain section by class. For Example, I would want to remove the "header" class from that or just hide it. Something where you can't click on it or it doesn't show. I can use javascript or jQuery, doesn't really matter.

Any Ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: If the iframe is in a different domain, you can not touch the contents. Is that the case?

Comment: yes, that is the case